# PDF attachment is not good when sending as mail in .Net

Tags: .net, email, pdf

My application send mail with PDF attachment to different mail ids. I have problem when i send PDF with big size. The PDF doesn't look good. The color inside PDF is getting changed.

Does anyone come across this type of problem

The mail server is not limited with any message size

Comment: Are you sure the PDF you are sending doesn't look like that before you send it? I'd be highly suspicious of anyone suggesting the .net mail classes are changing your data in anyway whatsoever. They should just read from a stream.

Comment: Just to be sure: a) does a small PDF look good? b) when you save the "large" PDF, is it's size the same as the original? c) How big is "big"?

Comment: a) Yes small PDF looks good b) i am not generating any PDF, i use the PDF send by the client. the PDF looks good in the actual physical folder c)above 6 MB but not in all case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked after changing the encoding type from **QuotedPrintable** to **base64**

Answer (score 3):

The mail transfer alone shouldn't change the content of the PDF. Are you generating the PDF yourself, maybe there is where the error happens. Otherwise it could be some third party tool (firewall maybe) that modifies the attachement.

A workaround you could try is to zip the PDF before you send it and send the zipped document.

Comment: No i am not generating PDF myself. Some PDF transfer is good even when the size is greate. But the PDF is good in the physical folder all the time

Comment: So in the physical folder it looks ok and after you've send it using .NET classes it gets modified? Well either you are doing some transformation before you send it (you should show us the code you are using for sending the file) or it is another application that modifies the file on the way to the recipient (mail server, firewall).

Comment: when i zip and send the files,it looks good and i have no problem.I am not any transformation, i use system.net class to transfer the mails. it simply takes the files from the folder and send the attachment

Comment: Well as you haven't showed your code we have to suppose it is OK. So it looks that "someone" different modifies the files. Maybe you should try sending an email with a PDF (that has been changed during the transmission) manually and see if the problem also occurs.

Comment: tmpAttachementFile.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
aoMessage.Attachments.Add(tmpAttachementFile); This is my coding. When i send the same PDF manually using GMAIL its good.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can leave out setting the Transfer encoding but you can define the attachement like this: "Attachment at = new Attachment(yourPdfFile,
System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf); yourMailMessage.Attachements.Add(at);